# use effect run only when a state becomes false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

i use react and i have a state with name isModalOpen.

> ```
> const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
> ```

i have a useEffect function

> useEffect(() => {},[]);

i want my use effect run every time that my isModalOpen become to **false**(only false)

i wrote

> useEffect(()=>{},[!isModalOpen])

but this method run everytime that isModalOpen changed(true to false or false to true)

Comment: That's the behaviour of useEffect. It is called every time when the supplied state value is changed.

Comment: You don't run hooks conditionally. In the same way that you can't nest a hook declaration *inside* an if statement, they have to be top level. They run every time their dependencies change. The conditional logic should be **inside** the effect, Just check for the value in there, i.e. `useEffect(() => { if (!isModalOpen) {...} },[isModalOpen]);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The dependency array to useEffect is meant to inform useEffect to run when there is a change in value. So whether you pass isModalOpen or !isModalOpen, its one and the same thing as it just checks whether the value changed i.e false to true or true to false.

The way to conditionally execute something is to aadd a condition in the callback function

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!isModalOpen) {
        // write your code here
    }

},[isModalOpen]);
```

However, if at some point you want to access the old and new value both in useEffect, you can implement a `usePrevious` hook as mentioned in the [React Hook FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)

Answer (score 1):

you should write like this not your sample because every time you write a state in dependencies

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(!isModalOpen){
  // your statement
}
},[isModalOpen]);
```

array useEffect triggers when it changes

Answer (score 1):

Dependency array in useEffect contains those values which cause re-rendering of the component upon change in those values.
So have a condition to restrict your login as:

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(!isModalOpen){
//your logic
}
}, [isModalOpen])
```